# Custom NSWindow setAlphaValue and makeKeyAndOrderFront

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, window, nswindow

I have a custom window (matt gemells Transparent Window class) and I need to change the window's alpha value to achieve a fade in/out effect and perform a "makeKeyAndOrderFront:".

However this does not work.

What I did:

I imported the header:

```
#import "TransparentWindow.h"
```

Then tried:

```
[TransparentWindow setAlphaValue:0.5];

[TransparentWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
```

This gave me a warning that "Transparent Window" may not respond to either of the code above. So I attempted to implement the "setAlphaValue" into Transparent Window by adding:

```
- (void)setAlphaValue:(CGFloat)windowAlpha
{
    [super setAlphaValue:windowAlpha];   
}
```

but the 2 warnings won't go away. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> [TransparentWindow setAlphaValue:0.5];
> [TransparentWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
> ```
>
> This gave me a warning that "Transparent Window" may not respond to either of the code above.

That's because it (the TransparentWindow class) doesn't.

You need to send those messages to a TransparentWindow instance, not to the TransparentWindow class.

> So I attempted to implement the "setAlphaValue" into Transparent Window by adding:
>
> ```
> - (void)setAlphaValue:(CGFloat)windowAlpha
> {
>     [super setAlphaValue:windowAlpha];   
> }
> ```

If this NSWindow method had not existed, calling it from a method in a subclass would not solve that problem.